# Are simple extensions of isomorphic fields isomorphic?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

If $F(u) \cong F(v)$, and both are subfields of a larger extension, $K$, then for $k \in K$, is $F(u)(k) \cong F(v)(k)$?

Comment: Wouldn't $u\not=v=k$ give a trivial counterexample?

Comment: Even if the isomorphism carries $u$ to $v$?

Comment: Bear in mind I do not think the answer is yes, I just want to be 100% certain

Comment: @Nethesis: In Joachim's example the natural isomorphism carries $u$ to $v$.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.. For a very concrete example you can simply pick nonalgebraic extensions, say in $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{C}$. So let $F = \mathbb{Q}$, $u = \pi$ and $v = e$. Since both $u$ and $e$ are transcedent over $\mathbb{Q}$, the fields $\mathbb{Q}(u)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(v)$ are isomorphic, but as noted in the comments we can now pick $k = \pi$ for a clear counterexample.

Comment: How do we know that $\mathbb{Q}(\pi) \not\cong \mathbb{Q}(\pi)(e)$?

Comment: @Nethesis: We don't. We don't even know if $\{1, \pi, e\}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$. But cardinality arguments easily show that _some_ algebraically independent transcendentals must _exist_, so just choose two such instead.

Comment: Aii, I was too quick on that one, thanks @HenningMakholm!